# How to Speed up read_html runtime in r?

Tags: r, web-scraping, lapply

I have a character string of 400 URLs called URLs.
I have a loop that has been working for a while but now it takes way too long.  It used to just report the url as an error and then I would omit but its is getting hung up.

```
 dput(URLs)
c("http://www.chinadaily.com.cn/a/202102/04/WS601b5bd7a31024ad0baa736d.html", 
"http://www.xinhuanet.com/english/2021-02/02/c_139716479.htm", 
"http://www.china.org.cn/world/Off_the_Wire/2021-02/02/content_77181645.htm", 
"http://english.sina.com/world/af/2021-02-02/detail-ikftssap2511288.shtml", 
"https://www.beijingnews.net/news/267750643/fox-takes-clubhouse-lead-as-johnson-makes-move-in-saudi-arabia", 
"https://www.beijingnews.net/news/267768819/johnson-excited-for-season-after-second-saudi-title", 
"https://en.wtcf.org.cn/GlobalNews/2021020320227.html", "https://www.ladepeche.fr/2021/02/08/golf-un-top-4-royal-pour-victor-perez-9360378.php", 
"https://sport24.lefigaro.fr/golf/tour-europeen/actualites/victor-perez-dans-les-pas-de-dustin-johnson-en-arabie-saoudite-1032163", 
"https://sport24.lefigaro.fr/golf/tour-europeen/actualites/european-tour-victor-perez-a-longtemps-tenu-tete-a-dustin-johnson-en-arabie-saoudite-1032273", 
"https://www.france24.com/en/live-news/20210206-johnson-seizes-two-shot-lead-in-saudi-international", 
"https://www.france24.com/en/live-news/20210205-fox-takes-clubhouse-lead-as-johnson-makes-move-in-saudi-arabia", 
"https://www.france24.com/en/live-news/20210203-big-hitting-dechambeau-happy-to-take-longer-clubs-out-of-rivals-hands", 
"https://www.france24.com/en/live-news/20210203-as-bubble-life-drags-on-psychologists-say-cricketers-need-more-support", 
"https://www.sports.fr/golf/circuit-europeen/golf-perez-gratin-arabie-saoudite-426859.html", 
"https://www.sport.fr/golf/lopen-de-france-est-sauve-758291.shtm", 
"https://www.ffgolf.org/Actus/Pro/European-Tour/Saudi-International-ET-Perez-n-est-pas-passe-loin", 
"https://www.ffgolf.org/Actus/Pro/European-Tour/Saudi-International-ET-Perez-a-rendez-vous-avec-DJ-dimanche", 
"https://www.ffgolf.org/Actus/Pro/European-Tour/Saudi-International-ET-Rozner-au-sec-a-6-Perez-a-7", 
"https://www.ffgolf.org/Actus/Pro/European-Tour/Saudi-International-ET-Rozner-et-Perez-demarrent-bien", 
"https://www.ffgolf.org/Actus/Pro/LPGA-Tour/Franck-Riboud-On-va-pouvoir-continuer-a-travailler-sereinement", 
"https://www.ffgolf.org/Actus/Pro/Feuilletons/Paroles-de-coach/Paroles-de-coach-6-Gwladys-Nocera", 
"https://franceracing.fr/other/porsche-et-tag-heuer-scellent-un-partenariat-strategique/", 
"https://www.rfi.fr/en/sports/20210206-johnson-seizes-two-shot-lead-in-saudi-international", 
"https://www.rfi.fr/en/sports/20210205-fox-takes-clubhouse-lead-as-johnson-makes-move-in-saudi-arabia", 
"https://www.rfi.fr/en/sports/20210203-big-hitting-dechambeau-happy-to-take-longer-clubs-out-of-rivals-hands", 
"https://www.rfi.fr/en/sports/20210203-as-bubble-life-drags-on-psychologists-say-cricketers-need-more-support", 
"https://www.jeudegolf.org/EasyBlog/Agathe-sauzon.html", "http://topactu.net/2021/02/viktor-hovland-vaults-into-farmers-lead-at-wet-torrey-pines/", 
"https://www.sueddeutsche.de/sport/golf-kaymer-18-bei-golf-turnier-in-saudi-arabien-johnson-siegt-dpa.urn-newsml-dpa-com-20090101-210207-99-337940", 
"https://www1.wdr.de/sport/golf-martin-kaymer-saudi-arabien-100.html", 
"https://www.augsburger-allgemeine.de/sport/sonstige-sportarten/Kaymer-18-bei-Golf-Turnier-in-Saudi-Arabien-Johnson-siegt-id59059886.html", 
"https://www.schwaebische.de/sport/ueberregionaler-sport_artikel,-kaymer-18-bei-golf-turnier-in-saudi-arabien-johnson-siegt-_arid,11325827.html", 
"https://www.sport.de/news/ne4341625/golf--kaymer-beendet-turnier-in-saudi-arabien-als-18/", 
"https://www.mz-web.de/sport/golf/kaymer-18--bei-golf-turnier-in-saudi-arabien---johnson-siegt-38027428", 
"https://www.nwzonline.de/sport-meldungen/european-tour-kaymer-18-bei-golf-turnier-in-saudi-arabien-johnson-siegt_a_50,12,475833623.html", 
"https://www.volksstimme.de/golf/news/kaymer-18.-bei-golf-turnier-in-saudi-arabien---johnson-siegt/1612702615000", 
"https://www.wn.de/Sport/Weltsport/Golf/4360897-European-Tour-Kaymer-18.-bei-Golf-Turnier-in-Saudi-Arabien-Johnson-siegt", 
"https://www.mainpost.de/sport/kaymer-18-bei-golf-turnier-in-saudi-arabien-johnson-siegt-art-10562664", 
"https://www.moz.de/nachrichten/sport/news/european-tour-kaymer-18.-bei-golf-turnier-in-saudi-arabien-johnson-siegt-54931493.html", 
"https://www.svz.de/sport/weitere-sportarten/kaymer-18-bei-golf-turnier-in-saudi-arabien-johnson-siegt-id31187247.html?nojs=true", 
"https://www.rhein-zeitung.de/sport/aus-aller-welt/aus-aller-welt-golf_artikel,-kaymer-18-bei-golfturnier-in-saudiarabien-johnson-siegt-_arid,2220135.html", 
"https://www.rhein-zeitung.de/sport/aus-aller-welt/aus-aller-welt-golf_artikel,-martin-kaymer-sagt-olympiastart-in-tokio-ab-_arid,2274019.html", 
"https://www.allgemeine-zeitung.de/sport/golf/kaymer-18-bei-golf-turnier-in-saudi-arabien-johnson-siegt_23109750", 
"https://www.echo-online.de/sport/golf/kaymer-18-bei-golf-turnier-in-saudi-arabien-johnson-siegt_23109750", 
"https://www.mittelhessen.de/sport/golf/kaymer-18-bei-golf-turnier-in-saudi-arabien-johnson-siegt_23109750", 
"https://www.muensterschezeitung.de/Sport/Sportarten/Golf/4360897-European-Tour-Kaymer-18.-bei-Golf-Turnier-in-Saudi-Arabien-Johnson-siegt", 
"https://www.wiesbadener-kurier.de/sport/golf/kaymer-18-bei-golf-turnier-in-saudi-arabien-johnson-siegt_23109750", 
"https://www.giessener-anzeiger.de/sport/golf/kaymer-18-bei-golf-turnier-in-saudi-arabien-johnson-siegt_23109750", 
"https://newsroom.porsche.com/de/2021/unternehmen/porsche-sportwagenhersteller-tag-heuer-luxusuhren-schmiede-zusammenarbeit-videostream-23558.html", 
"https://www.azonline.de/Sport/Weitere-Sportarten/Golf/4360897-European-Tour-Kaymer-18.-bei-Golf-Turnier-in-Saudi-Arabien-Johnson-siegt", 
"https://www.borkenerzeitung.de/welt/sport/Kaymer-18-bei-Golf-Turnier-in-Saudi-Arabien-Johnson-siegt-327224.html", 
"https://www.golfpost.de/european-tour-saudi-international-2021-ergebnisse-runde-2-7777396527/", 
"https://www.golfpost.de/396354-7777396354/", "https://www.golfpost.de/german-challenge-powerd-by-vcg-golf-challenge-tour-kehrt-nach-deutschland-zurueck-7777396396/", 
"https://www.golfpost.de/die-macht-der-moneten-saudi-arabien-auf-dem-weg-zum-big-player-im-golf-7777396387/", 
"https://www.kreis-anzeiger.de/sport/golf/kaymer-18-bei-golf-turnier-in-saudi-arabien-johnson-siegt_23109750", 
"https://www.wormser-zeitung.de/sport/golf/kaymer-18-bei-golf-turnier-in-saudi-arabien-johnson-siegt_23109750", 
"https://m.azonline.de/Sport/Weitere-Sportarten/Golf/4361712-PGA-Turnier-US-Golfstar-Koepka-triumphiert-bei-Phoenix-Open", 
"https://www.mv-online.de/sport/sportmix/kaymer-18-bei-golf-turnier-in-saudi-arabien-johnson-siegt-409658.html", 
"https://www.golf.de/publish/dgv-sport/golf-team-germany/news/60228375/sophia-popov-nach-major-sieg-in-elite-team-germany", 
"https://www.golf.de/publish/tournews/nachrichten-tour/60228372/einmal-saudi-einmal-etwas-gaudi", 
"https://www.golf.de/publish/tournews/nachrichten-tour/60228387/koepka-comeback-und-eine-wuestenbilanz", 
"https://www.ev-online.de/sport/sportmix/kaymer-18-bei-golf-turnier-in-saudi-arabien-johnson-siegt-409655.html", 
"https://www.nach-welt.com/dustin-johnson-setzt-masstabe-aber-jordan-spieth-justin-rose-und-brooks-koepka-kehren-zur-form-zuruck/", 
"https://www.nach-welt.com/ryan-fox-wird-sechster-wahrend-dustin-johnson-saudi-international-gewinnt/", 
"https://www.usinger-anzeiger.de/sport/golf/kaymer-18-bei-golf-turnier-in-saudi-arabien-johnson-siegt_23109750", 
"https://www.gaeubote.de/Nachrichten/Golf-Turnier-in-Muenchen-Kaymer-faellt-zurueck-86604.html", 
"https://www.gaeubote.de/Nachrichten/Kaymer-nach-Traumrunde-Zweiter-bei-Golf-Turnier-in-Muenchen-86664.html", 
"https://www.main-spitze.de/sport/golf/kaymer-18-bei-golf-turnier-in-saudi-arabien-johnson-siegt_23109750", 
"https://www.lauterbacher-anzeiger.de/sport/golf/kaymer-18-bei-golf-turnier-in-saudi-arabien-johnson-siegt_23109750", 
"https://www.oberhessische-zeitung.de/sport/golf/kaymer-18-bei-golf-turnier-in-saudi-arabien-johnson-siegt_23109750", 
"https://de.advfn.com/p.php?pid=nmona&article=84265497", "https://www.buerstaedter-zeitung.de/sport/golf/kaymer-18-bei-golf-turnier-in-saudi-arabien-johnson-siegt_23109750", 
"https://www.golftime.de/golf-nachrichten/challenge-tour-in-deutschland-neues-profi-turnier/", 
"https://www.golftime.de/golf-nachrichten/martin-kaymer-saudi-international-tour-news/", 
"https://www.golftime.de/magazin/distanz-usga-ra-elite-spieler-regel-anpassung/", 
"https://www.dmm.travel/nc/news/porsche-und-tag-heuer-arbeiten-zusammen/", 
"https://www.lampertheimer-zeitung.de/sport/golf/kaymer-18-bei-golf-turnier-in-saudi-arabien-johnson-siegt_23109750", 
"https://www.hongkongherald.com/news/267768819/johnson-excited-for-season-after-second-saudi-title", 
"https://www.hongkongherald.com/news/267750643/fox-takes-clubhouse-lead-as-johnson-makes-move-in-saudi-arabia", 
"http://hongkongcityportal.com/saudi-international-englands-david-horsey-leads-from-scotlands-stephen-gallacher/", 
"http://hongkongcityportal.com/bryson-dechambeau-flattered-and-welcomes-proposed-rule-changes/", 
"http://hongkongcityportal.com/paul-casey-englishman-defends-saudi-international-u-turn/", 
"https://as.com/masdeporte/2021/02/03/golf/1612378989_020231.html", 
"https://www.marca.com/golf/2021/02/07/601fd7c122601d860c8b45dc.html", 
"https://www.marca.com/golf/2021/05/02/608ece1b22601d9d5d8b45f0.html", 
"https://www.marca.com/golf/2021/02/03/601ad5d7268e3ef01e8b4670.html", 
"https://www.republicworld.com/sports-news/other-sports/johnson-eases-to-another-victory-at-saudi-international.html", 
"https://www.republicworld.com/sports-news/other-sports/dustin-johnson-within-1-shot-of-lead-at-saudi-international.html", 
"https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/sports/golf/top-stories/dustin-johnson-excited-for-season-after-second-saudi-title/articleshow/80737390.cms", 
"https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/sports/golf/top-stories/johnson-eases-to-another-victory-at-saudi-international/articleshow/80736264.cms", 
"https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/sports/golf/top-stories/ryan-fox-takes-surprise-lead-at-saudi-international/articleshow/80711869.cms", 
"https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/sports/golf/top-stories/horsey-goes-on-birdie-blitz-for-saudi-international-lead/articleshow/80691513.cms", 
"https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/sports/golf/top-stories/shubhankar-shoots-69-in-opening-round-at-saudi-international/articleshow/80691501.cms", 
"https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/sports/golf/top-stories/big-hitting-dechambeau-happy-to-take-longer-clubs-out-of-rivals-hands/articleshow/80672723.cms", 
"https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/sports/cricket/news/as-bubble-life-drags-on-psychologists-say-cricketers-need-more-support/articleshow/80662353.cms", 
"https://www.abc.es/deportes/abci-sergio-garcia-apunta-ryder-202102070038_noticia.html", 
"https://www.abc.es/deportes/abci-golfistas-golpe-gimnasio-202102050031_noticia.html", 
"https://www.investing.com/news/general/golf-johnson-holds-on-to-clinch-second-saudi-international-title-2411514"
)
```

```
####I have tried this:
html_reader<- function(x){return( tryCatch(xml2::read_html(URLs[k]), error = function(e) NULL))}

for (k in seq_along(URLs)) parsed_pages[k] <-lapply(as.list(URLs), html_reader)
```

I havent run into issues with runtime for some reason until now.   The function will not complete even with the try() error function.
My current working code is the following:

```
pp <- replicate(list(), n = length(ESPN))
for (k in seq_along(ESPN)) pp[[k]] <- try(xml2::read_html(ESPN[k]), silent = TRUE)
```

It used to just take a while but now it never finishes.

Comment: Try adding a `cat(i)` into your loop and see what number you reach before it freezes. Then you can investigate whether there is a problem with that particular url.

Comment: @AllanCameron can you write out the code to where you are considering the edit?  .... additionally, I run this for a weekly report... It is a random sample so it doesnt matter which URL is holding it up as long as it skips that url and doesnt hold up the script....right now it is set up to do that but the runtime before it skips is taking too long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue I am running into is due to the open connections.   The script would get progressively slower and I feel it was due to the old connections.  Here is a simple loop that closes out all of the connections.  I will know when I run a particular report again if this is the solution but it has seemed to help so far.

```
for (i in seq_along(df$URLs)){function(i)
  closeAllConnections(i)
}
```